# What's wrong with that code?

Tags: cross-referencing, counters

```
\def\totalobjects@putlabel{%
 \addtocounter{totalpage}{\c@page}
 \immediate\write\@auxout{\string
   \newlabel{reftotaltables}{{}{\refstepcounter{totalpage}}{\relax }{}{}}}
}
\AtEndDocument{\totalobjects@putlabel}
```

Or how I can make next work:

```
\def\totalobjects@putlabel{%
 \addtocounter{totalpage}{\c@page}
 \refstepcounter{totalpage}\label{reftotalpages}
}
\AtEndDocument{\totalobjects@putlabel}
```

I am using XeLaTeX. After using the second snippet, label doesn't work (I see «??», when refer to it). After using the first snippet, I receive compile errors.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Without a minimal example it's difficult to say. Do you want to have a page numbering of the form “page n of m”? If so, look at the `lastpage` package.

Comment: @egreg I also have another counters (for figures, bibliography and tables), so it is needed to add a label with calculated counter to the end of the document. The second snippet will work, if I add \null or \newpage before \addtocounter, but both of \null and \newpage adds new empty page to the end of my document. How I can escape from this? The first one perfectly works with \thepage instead of \refstepcounter{totalpage} (I also have tried \value{totalpage}).

Comment: `\usepackage{totcount}`, if you don't want to reinvent the wheel. `;-)`

Answer (score 1):

Writes to the `.aux` files happen when a page is shipped out, unless `\write` is preceded by `\immediate`, as in your first code.

However, the first code can't work, because the page number is unpredictable unless LaTeX is shipping out a page or has just shipped out one: the page number counter is stepped at the end of the shipout procedure. So an `\immediate\write` is not guaranteed to work reliably.

With the second code you use `\label`, which in turn relies on writing to the `.aux` file but without `\immediate`, so the corresponding `\newlabel` command can be written out only at the next shipout. But there is *no* next shipout when you put the code in `\AtEndDocument`.

You could use the `atveryend` package for solving the issue; but if all you need is to write something in the `.aux` file to have available the final value of some counters, then the `totcount` package already does it for you.

With

```
\usepackage{totcount}
\regtotcounter{section}
```

in your document preamble, you can type `\total{section}` anywhere you need to print the highest section number in the document.

For having a reference to the last page number, do

```
\usepackage{lastpage}
```

and use `\pageref{LastPage}` where you want the last page number. Or use `zref` that has a very extensible mechanism.